# SQL Filtering through duplicate IDs for multiple values

Tags: sql

Hello I am trying to performe a count query in SQL where it will tell me the number of IDS that have 2 specific codes attached to them. The issue I am having is with the structure of the table.

[image]

So for example I know Patient_ID ZZZZZ02SDU has a CPT_code of 2022F and 3060F but they are both on separate rows.

How Can I combine all the duplicate IDs to count once and all the CPT_codes attached to those patient_id rows to be filtered through also?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the CPT_codes attached to those patient_id rows to be filtered through"? Could you provide an example of the output you'd like?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the HAVING filter -- it will happen after the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT PATIENT_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT CPT_CODE)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY PATIENT_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CPT_CODE) > 1
```

This will give you all PATIENT_IDs that have more than one CPT_CODE.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from (
  select count(*) AS S from table group by Patient_id having count(*)=2)
group S;
```

As the op asked for only the count I have at first grouped the table rows by Patient_id and each having 2 entries and then those are basically counted and put as an answer in the outermost query.

Comment: Can you please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and  future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT.: Check my answer...btw thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in SQL Server or Oracle you can use the following SQL:

```
WITH PatientMedicalCodes AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Patient_ID, CPT_code
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT Patient_ID, COUNT(CPT_code)
FROM PatientMedicalCodes
GROUP BY Patient_ID
HAVING COUNT(CPT_code) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if thos specific codes are this:

```
select distinct a. patient_id 
  from mytable a inner join mytable b 
    on a.patient_id=b.patient_id
where a.cpt_code='2022F' and b.cpt_code='3060F'
```